# Why does this SQL query kill my server?

Tags: php, sql-server, ajax, query-optimization, varnish

When I run this query on SQL server from a Varnish cache server.

```
select count(distinct email) from aiki_users, ocal_files where userid = 
       (select upload_user from ocal_files where upload_user = userid limit 1)
```

With `aiki_users` table having >  80000 rows

and the `ocal_files` table having > 30000 rows.

It kills the server. It is called from a php script via ajax. I have to close the page that calls it.

I don't know what it returns, but I know that the thing I want to do should be created with group by and having, but I don't know how.

The aiki_users table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `aiki_users` (
  `userid` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `full_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sex` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `job` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `oauth_passcode` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `oauth_token` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `oauth_token_secret` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `usergroup` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `avatar` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `homepage` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `first_ip` varchar(40) NOT NULL default '0',
  `first_login` datetime NOT NULL,
  `last_login` datetime NOT NULL,
  `last_ip` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `user_permissions` text NOT NULL,
  `maillist` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `logins_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `randkey` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` int(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`userid`),
  KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

I don't have correct access to the server, I can't see the defnition of ocal_files but:

```
 ocal_files.aiki_users = aiki_users.userid
```

Can anybody tell me how bad the query is and what it returns?

Comment: What exactly is this query trying to do in natural language? When someone reading it can't easily figure out a 2-line query, things are bad indeed.

Comment: it would help to post the tables structures, at least the columns involved in the query, and how they relate to each other, then perhaps we can help optimizing it for you

Comment: That looks like `MySql` not SQL Server. Can you tag correctly.

Comment: It suppost to count users that have files in ocal_files there are lots' of duplications (users create accounts multiple times because of bugs in the system) in database so I use distinct email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're selecting from both aiki_user and ocal_files in the main query, without specifying a join clause, the where in the nested query isn't going to stop the full table join...

Comment: I was about to give the same solution.  +1

Comment: +1 Another inadvertent cartesian join caused by not using explicit join syntax.

Comment: Wow. Now I see? Thanks. I forget to remove this one.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend running EXPLAIN PLAN on both queries and seeing what the database tells you.

My guess is that you have to do a TABLE SCAN, so the performance is terrible.

Comment: What are "EXPLAIN PLAN" and "TABLE SCAN"